# Have multiple check in/out/lunch time and get total hours

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms

I have 2 date time picker. assume that in my database already saved the data needed

```
//Status      //Date      //Time      //name
----------------------------------------------
Check In     1/8/2016    12:30:36pm     ali
  Lunch      1/8/2016     2:40:36pm     ali
Check In     1/8/2016     3:40:36pm     ali
Check Out    1/8/2016     6:40:36pm     ali
```

As i don't want to calculate the lunch time. as i want to calculate what my employee work for that day

```
6:40:36 PM - 12:30:36pm = 6 //total hours worked include lunch
```

So i have to subtract the Lunch - Checkk in which take 1 hours

```
6 - (3:40:36 PM - 2:40:36 PM) = 5 hours //total hours that worked
```

What kind of logic should i have to do this?
I already know all type of SQL clause to pick from my database. But i need a way that can calculate this easier without implementing huge lines of codes.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly robust and could probably do with some refactoring, but might give you a starting point to extend for your own logic.

Your states as an enum:

```
public enum Status
    {
        CheckIn,
        CheckOut,
        Lunch
    }
```

Turn your data into a list of these:

```
public class EmployeeStatusChange
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

        public Status Status { get; set; }
    }
```

And then use this extension method:

```
public static double CalculateHours(this List<EmployeeStatusChange> changes)
    {
        changes = changes.OrderBy(x => x.DateTime).ToList();

        double hours = 0;
        var start = DateTime.MinValue;
        var lunch = DateTime.MinValue;
        var checkedOut = false;

        foreach (var change in changes)
        {
            // exclude anything before the first check in, or if we have already checked out
            if ((start == DateTime.MinValue && change.Status != Status.CheckIn) || checkedOut)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Set the start time
            if (start == DateTime.MinValue && change.Status == Status.CheckIn)
            {
                start = change.DateTime;
                continue;
            }

            switch (change.Status)
            {
                case Status.CheckIn:
                    if (lunch == DateTime.MinValue)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    start = change.DateTime;
                    continue;

                case Status.Lunch:
                    lunch = change.DateTime;
                    hours += (change.DateTime - start).TotalHours;
                    break;

                case Status.CheckOut:
                    checkedOut = true;
                    hours += (change.DateTime - start).TotalHours;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return hours;
    }
```

This will return 6.5:

```
var items = new List<EmployeeStatusChange>();
items.Add(new EmployeeStatusChange { EmployeeId = 1, Status = Status.CheckIn, DateTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0) });
items.Add(new EmployeeStatusChange { EmployeeId = 1, Status = Status.Lunch, DateTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 10, 30, 0) });
items.Add(new EmployeeStatusChange { EmployeeId = 1, Status = Status.CheckIn, DateTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0) });
items.Add(new EmployeeStatusChange { EmployeeId = 1, Status = Status.Lunch, DateTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0) });
items.Add(new EmployeeStatusChange { EmployeeId = 1, Status = Status.CheckIn, DateTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0) });
items.Add(new EmployeeStatusChange { EmployeeId = 1, Status = Status.CheckOut, DateTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0) });
items.CalculateHours();
```